# Set IntVar in class' __init__(self) and recall IntVar variable outside that class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a class that defines a number of variables set to `IntVar()`, to later give them a value and recall them inside an `Entry` widget.

Right now I am trying:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class ESCP2_Client(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Entry(textvariable=SetVars.var1).pack()


class SetVars(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = tk.IntVar()


app = ESCP2_Client()

vars = SetVars()
print(vars.var1)


app.mainloop()
```

But this (obviously?) is not working. But I can't set the variable before the `__init__` function, since `IntVar()` needs a `Tk()` root.

How can I recall the `IntVar` that is defined in the other class?

Comment: Why do you need to set the values before you create the root window?

Comment: That is not the case, my bad, the window is already created, but the variable in the Entry widget must be accessible to multiple classes and functions. It can be global as well, but I don't know how and where to set global. I will edit the order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of `SetVars` and then use that instance everywhere you need access to the variables. For example, you could create it as part of the `__init__` of the client:

```
class ESCP2_Client(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.vars = SetVars()
        tk.Entry(textvariable=self.vars.var1).pack()
```

Other parts of the code can access them via the client:

```
print("var1:", app.vars.var1.get())
```